# (Not so) Ambiguous Call in MVC 4 Beta

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Playing around with MVC 4 Beta and its Mobile features, the following line in `Login.Mobile.cshtml`

@Html.Partial("_ViewSwitcher")

Causes this compiler error:

> The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 
>   'System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper, string)' and 
>   'System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper, string)'

[Per MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.partialextensions.aspx) this is defined in System.Web.Mvc (in System.Web.Mvc.dll), to which I only seem to have a single reference.

The application runs correctly in spite of the compiler error.

There are no `using` statements in the view, though the following namespaces are incorporated via `web.config`:

```
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
```

What's happening, and how can I get rid of the misleading compiler error?

Comment: What do your @using statements look like at the top of the view?

Comment: @ShaneCourtrille: No using statements, though some namespaces are incorporated via web.config.  Updated the question.

Comment: Does your layout have any @using statements?  Not sure if those get applied or not during compile time...

Comment: @Shane: No, it does not.

Comment: Any further word on how to fix this? I'm having the same problem. Very annoying.

Comment: @RobertMacGrogan: I don't see this issue in the ASP.Net 4 RTM version.

Answer (score 1):

The method is defined in two places is the usual cause for this, it can be from a referenced assembly of a previous build, the compiler will pick the most likely and use it so won't halt processing.

Comment: True, but I can not see how I could be referencing the same System.Web.Mvc.dll twice, nor should that method be defined in any other assembly.

Comment: Forgot, the other way is if you have a x64 folder to build to and the std folder the built dll ends up in, you get the ambiguous error that way.